# Xamarin Studio 5.9 can't find FSharp.Core for an F# Library project

Tags: f#, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am running Xamarin Studio 5.9 (build 431). And I have a C# project referencing a F# library. And somehow the FSharp.Core.dll file is not found by Xamarin Studio. The error I get is below.

```
Could not load file or assembly 
'FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

The target on both projects is Android 4.4. And I can see that FSharp.Core is selected (v 2.3.98.1). I tried installing the fsharp bundle, except that I am not sure where the files got copied. I tried restarting just in case Xamarin Studio may just find the files, but did not work. I tried referencing the assembly directly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp.NETPortable\2.3.5.1\FSharp.Core.dll" And that did not work either. The only reference I find in the project file is `<Reference Include="FSharp.Core" />` I could try to redirect it, but there are no config files in Xamarin Studio that I know of.

I'm not sure what else to try.

EDIT:

It seems like the GAC has version 2.3.0.0 and the current version is 2.3.98.1 I think I will replace it. But I'm not sure what profile is needed for Xamarin Studio.

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7278/xamarin-studio-not-loading-any-project-after-adding-fsharp-add-in-from-tools) in the Xamarin support site has a the solution that worked for me.

Installing the ["Free F# Compiler Tools"](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/5/E/05E5C5E3-2A52-434F-A09E-C8150B987D09/VWD_FSharp.exe) took care of the problem. Apparently the current SDK is not the one Xamarin expects.